# What is the command to augment extreme scale on non-federated environment

Tags: websphere

If the command to augment a extreme scale in Websphere is this:

```
 $WAS_PATH/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -hostName $THIS_HOSTNAME -profileName xsSrv01 -profilePath $WAS_PATH/profiles/xsSrv01/ -templatePath $WAS_PATH/profileTemplates/xs_augment/managed/ -nodeName xsNode01 -dmgrHost $THIS_HOSTNAME
```

what is the command to augment on a non-federated host? Something like this:

```
$WAS_PATH/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName xsSrv01 -templatePath $WAS_PATH/profileTemplates/xs_augment/default/  -nodeName AppSrvNode01
```

I am setting up a test environment for devs but running into some issues with Extreme Scale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation on how to do extreme scale augmentation here:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTVLU_8.6.1/com.ibm.websphere.extremescale.doc/rxspmtmngprf.html

Based off of your description of what you are trying to augment, your example of how to do it using the default augment template is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$WAS_PATH/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName AppSrv01 -templatePath $WAS_PATH/profileTemplates/xs_augment/default -enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName admin -adminPassword admin -nodeName AppSrvNode01 -serverName $SERVERNAME
```